# margin-right of div within position=fixed div

Tags: html, css

What I want: two small "back to the top" buttons, each in their own div. This div pair is within an outer div.

One button-div should be left-aligned in that outer div, the other button-div should be right-aligned. The idea is to have them "straddle" my page-container div.

All is well - until I give the outer-div a "position:fixed" and "top:70%", to move them down in the viewport.

So far, I have found no way to right-align the right button-div; margin-right has no effect, even if I remove the left button (in case its alignment impacts the element(s) that follow).

The basic approach is:

```
<div class="tabs1">
<div>
    <a href="#top-of-page">           
        <div class="right1">
            <font color="#FF0000">◄</font> Top
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#top-of-page">
        <div class="left1">
            <font color="#FF0000">◄</font> Top
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have provided the above in **fiddle** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Stringer/kxus9bwL/4/), both with & without vertical positioning.

The "results" window of the fiddle shows two pairs of "top" buttons. The pair at the top behaves like I want them to, until I try to move them down from the top of the viewport.

The second pair shows what all my attempts end up with: both buttons on the left of the page body/container div. In the fiddle, I have separated them vertically, otherwise they'd be on top of each other.

What's the "trick"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `right` attribute; for example `right: 10px;`. And if you want it symmetric, you can use `left` for the left one.

**EDIT:**

OK, I misunderstood the question a bit. I'll try again:
If you want the distance between the two buttons constant you can add a `left: 50%;` and then correct the positioning by adding a left margin half as big as the width. So that would look like this:

```
.tabs2 {
    width:250px;
    position:fixed;
    top:60%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -125px;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

And if you only want this behavior starting at a certain screen-width you could add a media-query like so:

```
.tabs2 {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 250px;
    position:fixed;
    top:60%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
@media (min-width: 250px) {
    .tabs2 {
        margin-left: -125px;
    }
}
```

Although I'm not sure this is the most ideal or clean way of doing it.

Comment: Indeed, but only for a single viewport width: the button on the left will always be at a fixed distance from the page-container, unless the viewport width is reduced such that the page-container width becomes smaller than its specified max-width.

Comment: The button on the RIGHT moves away from the right edge of the page-container - further inside the page-container if the viewport shrinks, and away from the page-container edge if the viewport becomes larger than the page-container max-width. You can see this if you change the viewport width in the fiddle.

Comment: @Fred OK, I changed my answer, hope I got it right now :)

Comment: Thanks kalyan! Can your solution be generalized from  .tabs2 that has a fixed "width:250px", to handle "width:100%; max-width:250px"?